# Django - Allauth default email is bad

Tags: django, email, django-allauth

I am using Allauth to handle the authentication happening on my website. And I am also using Mailgun for sending mail, connecting to it via SMTP. Now, in production, whenever I register a new account an confirmation mail is sent to me (per default via allauth). However, to my dismay the mail I got it from is extremely ugly (see picture below). Is there a way to resolve this?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

add `DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = 'noreply@yourdomain.com'` to your settings.py that should fix it.

Comment: thanks. your answer worked for me with django 4.2, allauth 0.56.1 and cpanel 110.0 in 2023